# SharePoint 2016 my sites is redirecting to onedrive.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server, onedrive, mysites

I have recently migrated the my sites content database from one SharePoint 2016 farm to another SharePoint 2016 farm using standard SharePoint content database backup restore method.

In source SharePoint 2016 farm, when I open my site, it is opening https://mysite.domain.com/personal/user/Documents/Forms/All.aspx.

In target SharePoint 2016 farm, when I open my site, it is opening https://mysite.domain.com/personal/user/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx.

And this onedrive.aspx page is blank.

Difference between these two SharePoint 2016 farms:

- Source environment uses SQL Serer 2014 and "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard" Operating System.
- Target environment uses SQL Server 2017 and "Windows Server 2022 Datacenter" Operating System.

What steps are required to fix this such that my sites go to standard All.aspx, instead of onedrive.aspx.

Or what is required to make onedrive.aspx page to work (it is blank page now).